# Checking for units with Pandera

Tags: python, pandera

Recently started using Pandera; what an excellent Python Package!

Does anyone know if it is possible to include so-called metadata of a column into the SchemaModel of a dataframe? For instance, add the unit of a column (seconds, kilometers, etc.).

Consider the following situation. I have two pandas Dataframes (say *df1* and *df2*), each with a column *distance*. Now suppose I merge these two dataframes over some keys into a new dataframe called *df_merged*, and then take the sum of both distance columns. It would be great to validate whether both distance units are equal (e.g., both *km*, or both *cm*) when validating the resulting dataframe.

I guess it would mean that the Input schemas of *df1* and *df2* would include some kind of metadata of the distance columns, and that Pandera checks whether the units are compatible.

Is this possible with Pandera, or do I need to implement this differently?

Comment: I suggest you put sample data to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give example data, so I'll assume that the metadata is just another column in the schema. If you only want to check if a dataframe is *valid*, that's straight-forward with the existing `Check` interface:

```py
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Series
from pandera import extensions
import pandas as pd


@extensions.register_check_method(supported_types=pd.Series)
def uniform(series: pd.Series):
    uniques = series.unique()
    if len(uniques) != 1:
        return pd.Series([False] * len(series))


class Schema(pa.SchemaModel):
    distance: Series[float]
    unit: Series[str] = pa.Field(uniform=())
```

Example:

```py
>>> Schema.validate(pd.DataFrame({
...     "distance": [1212., 3431., 4.],
...     "unit": ["m", "m", "km"],
... }))
Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
    raise errors.SchemaError(
pandera.errors.SchemaError: <Schema Column(name=unit, type=DataType(str))> failed element-wise validator 0:
<Check uniform>
failure cases:
   index failure_case
0      0            m
1      1            m
2      2           km
```

If you want to also handle the ensuing transformation (e.g. "find the most frequent unit and try to convert all other rows into it") in pandera, you're out of luck. [It's been proposed](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/252) multiple times and has a good chance of getting implemented, but it's not there yet.